# The best way to create php rabbit worker

Tags: php, rabbitmq, infinite-loop, worker

Assume I have rabbit queue that is filled with some data very often (e.g. user provides some action that we need to analyse later). From 30 till 50 new items are added each second.
What I need is to create a worker that will look through this queue and perform some tasks over that data. I can do like this:

```
class Worker
{

    public function run()
    {
        $queue = new Queue('exchange', 'queue');
        while (true)
        {
            $queue->processQueue();
        }
    }
}
```

And then just run `worker.php` on the server and that seems to be working.

But I wonder if this infinite loop will add extra load to my rabbit instance if there are no data to proceed? Maybe a better way is to do something like:

```
class Worker
{
    CONST IDLE = 5;

    private $start = 0;

    public function run()
    {
        $this->start = time();

        $queue = new Queue('exchange', 'queue');
        while (true)
        {
            $queue->processQueue();

            //don't allow this worker to be working a lot
            if (time() - $this->start >= 60 * 60 - self::IDLE)
            {
                break;
            }

            sleep(self::IDLE);
        }

        $queue->close();
    }
}
```

So my work will not pull data from rabbit continuously but sleep for a while. And after one hour of work it will just stop working and another instance of worker will be invoked by crontab job or something else?

Answer (score 3):

In order to manage my workers with rabbitmq I use the following library:

https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib

Then I create a class that defines how my workers should work (contains all the rabbitmq logic), it gives me something like this:

```
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

abstract class QueueAMQPConsumer
{    
    protected $connection;

    protected $debug;

    protected $queueName;

    protected $exchange;

    public function __construct(AMQPStreamConnection $AMQPConnection, $queueName, $exchange = null)
    {
        $this->connection = $AMQPConnection;
        $this->queueName = $queueName;
        $this->exchange = $exchange;
    }

    public function run($debug = false)
    {
        $this->debug = $debug;
        $channel = $this->connection->channel();
        if ($this->exchange !== null) {
            $channel->exchange_declare($this->exchange, "topic", false, true, false);
        }

        $channel->queue_declare($this->queueName, false, true, false, false);
        if ($this->exchange !== null) {
            $channel->queue_bind($this->queueName, $this->exchange);
        }

        $channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
        $channel->basic_consume($this->queueName, '', false, false, false, false, [$this, 'callback']);

        while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
            $channel->wait();
        }

        $channel->close();
        $this->connection->close();
    }


    final function callback(AMQPMessage $message)
    {
        $result = $this->process($message);

        if (false === $result) {
            $message->delivery_info['channel']->basic_nack($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag'], false, true);
        } else {
            $message->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($message->   delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param AMQPMessage $message
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    abstract protected function process(AMQPMessage $message);
}
```

This class allows to set up the queue, exchange (a topic in this case), QoS (you can custom all these parameters, it's just an example) etc..

Then it will loop on the callback. Here the callback is the abstract method process(...) that will be implemented on your different workers that need to process the queue. So the responsibility of the "loop/listening" is on the channel: `$channel->wait();`

Then I will create a child class that needs to process messages in the queue:

```
class MyWorker extends QueueAMQPConsumer
{
    protected function process(AMQPMessage $message)
    {   
       // .... process your message here
    }
}
```

So the worker will be listening to your queue all the time and will process the messages at the moment they arrived in the queue. 
If your `process(...)` return something else than false, the message will be acknowledged.

You just have to launch your class like that:

```
$consumer = new MyWorker(....);    
$consumer->run();
```